# Speech to Text - recognise the speaker's

Tags: python, google-speech-to-text-api

I am having an issue where we want to transcribe some audio of a press conference.

However it is not picking up when the speakers change.

For this demo I'll use a YouTube press conference (our script downloads it as mp3)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3fFkMrTYZTs

In this video there are 3 speakers.

Speaker 1 is from 00:00
speaker 2 is from 02:02
Speaker 3 is from 04:10

However the transcript is not picking this up. How can I improve my Python code to better recognise when each of these people are speaking.

Function to transcribe audio using Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API

```
# Function to transcribe audio using Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API
def transcribe_audio(audio_file):
    client = speech.SpeechClient()

    

    config = speech.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding=speech.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.MP3,
        sample_rate_hertz=48000,
        language_code="en-US",
        audio_channel_count=2,
        enable_automatic_punctuation=True,
        diarization_config={
            "enable_speaker_diarization": True,
            "min_speaker_count": 2,
            "max_speaker_count": 6,
            
        },
        speech_contexts=[
                speech.SpeechContext(
                phrases=["Australia", "United States", "United Kingdom"]
            )
        ],
        enable_word_time_offsets=True,
    )
    uri = audio_file
    # Perform asynchronous speech recognition
    audio = speech.RecognitionAudio(uri=uri)
    operation = client.long_running_recognize(config=config, audio=audio)
    response = operation.result(timeout=1000)

    # Process the transcription results
    transcription = ""
    speaker_tags = []
    for result in response.results:
        alternative = result.alternatives[0]
        transcription += alternative.transcript.strip() + " "
        speaker_tags += alternative.words

    return transcription, speaker_tags
```

The code above gets called via:

```
transcription, speaker_tags = transcribe_audio(audio_file)
#print("transcript:",transcription)
#print("Speaker tags:", speaker_tags)
speaker_dict = {}
current_speaker = ""
for tag in speaker_tags:
    speaker = "Speaker_" + str(tag.speaker_tag)
    if current_speaker != speaker:
        current_speaker = speaker
        speaker_dict[current_speaker] = ""
    speaker_dict[current_speaker] += " " + tag.word
transcript = ""
for speaker, text in speaker_dict.items():
    transcript += speaker + ":" + text + "\n"
print(transcript)
```

However when it does transcribe it I get transcription back I get this:

```
Speaker_0: I've always said when I asked the United States is Pacific, Power United States. Route to Pacific Islanders and kept the sea Lanes in Skies open and navigable for all the basic rules of the road and fuels International Commerce. And our Partnerships have helped underwrite credible growth and Innovation. Today Prospect a piece for decades to come United States. Could ask for no better Partners in the end up as if he were so much. Washington State partnership for showing again, how democracies can deliver our own security and prosperity and not just for us. But for the entire world Day stuff to carry out, our first project under office and developing Australia's conventionally armed nuclear, powered, submarine capacity to be clear. One recruit everyone from the outset right off the bat, there's no confusion Subs, not your arm, supposed to clear up our route. These both want each of us standing here today. Australia. Deeply committed. Turn off the giant, new chapter in the relationship between the United States. And the United Kingdom begins a friendship on a shared values and vision for a peaceful and a prosperous future. The orcas agreement we can firm Hearing Center represents the biggest single investment in Australian Defence capability. In all of our history, strengthening security, and stability in every building a future investment in skills, jobs and infrastructure and delivering I used to. If any type of bility into the future, Bility security relationships across from Italy in the next check. I just driving will take delivery of three us virginia-class nuclear-powered, submarine BCC in 65 years and only the second time in history that the United States has its nuclear propulsion technology. And we thank you for We are also proud to partner with the United Kingdom, to construct the Next Generation submarine to be cool. If I say no, and you conventionally armed nuclear powered submarine by Stone, the British design and incorporating cutting-edge Australian UK and US Technologies. This will be an Australian Sovereign capability built by aliens with construction to begin 60 years ago. The maintenance of Freedom, peace and security. Today, we stand together and recognizing just be hopeful window. and the lost by Russia in the legal invasion of Ukraine has growing assertiveness, the destabilizing the School threatened to create a world defined by danger disorder and Division, Brace for this new reality, it is more important than ever that we strengthen the resilience of our own country. That's why the UK and today announced a significant amount of Defense budget with providing an extra ten pounds over the next two years and need you to send it. This will allow us to replenish our. And modernize our nuclear Enterprise delivering orcas and strengthening Elgin Tavern.
Speaker_1: The maintenance of Freedom, peace and security. Today, we stand together and recognizing just be hopeful window. and the lost by Russia in the legal invasion of Ukraine has growing assertiveness, the destabilizing the School threatened to create a world defined by danger disorder and Division, Brace for this new reality, it is more important than ever that we strengthen the resilience of our own country. That's why the UK and today announced a significant amount of Defense budget with providing an extra ten pounds over the next two years and need you to send it. This will allow us to replenish our. And modernize our nuclear Enterprise delivering orcas and strengthening Elgin Tavern.
Speaker_2: peaceful and a prosperous future. The orcas agreement we can firm Hearing Center represents the biggest single investment in Australian Defence capability. In all of our history, strengthening security, and stability in every building a future investment in skills, jobs and infrastructure and delivering I used to. If any type of bility into the future, Bility security relationships across from Italy in the next check. I just driving will take delivery of three us virginia-class nuclear-powered, submarine BCC in 65 years and only the second time in history that the United States has its nuclear propulsion technology. And we thank you for We are also proud to partner with the United Kingdom, to construct the Next Generation submarine to be cool. If I say no, and you conventionally armed nuclear powered submarine by Stone, the British design and incorporating cutting-edge Australian UK and US Technologies. This will be an Australian Sovereign capability built by aliens with construction to begin 60 years ago.
```

I also note that the transcription is so wrong and has not been able to transcribe it correct.

Answer (score 1):

When you send an audio transcription request to Speech-to-Text, you can include a parameter telling Speech-to-Text to identify the different speakers in the audio sample. This feature, called speaker diarization, detects when speakers change and labels by number the individual voices detected in the audio.

When you enable speaker diarization in your transcription request, Speech-to-Text attempts to distinguish the different voices included in the audio sample.

To enable speaker diarization, you need to set the `enableSpeakerDiarization` field to `true` in the [SpeakerDiarizationConfig](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1p1beta1/RecognitionConfig#SpeakerDiarizationConfig) parameters for the request.

The below sample code demonstrates how to enable speaker diarization in a transcription request to Speech-to-Text using a local file.

```
from google.cloud import speech_v1p1beta1 as speech

client = speech.SpeechClient()

speech_file = "resources/commercial_mono.wav"

with open(speech_file, "rb") as audio_file:
    content = audio_file.read()

audio = speech.RecognitionAudio(content=content)

diarization_config = speech.SpeakerDiarizationConfig(
    enable_speaker_diarization=True,
    min_speaker_count=2,
    max_speaker_count=10,
)

config = speech.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding=speech.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
    sample_rate_hertz=8000,
    language_code="en-US",
    diarization_config=diarization_config,
)

print("Waiting for operation to complete...")
response = client.recognize(config=config, audio=audio)

# The transcript within each result is separate and sequential per result.
# However, the words list within an alternative includes all the words
# from all the results thus far. Thus, to get all the words with speaker
# tags, you only have to take the words list from the last result:
result = response.results[-1]

words_info = result.alternatives[0].words

# Printing out the output:
for word_info in words_info:
    print(
        "word: '{}', speaker_tag: {}".format(word_info.word, word_info.speaker_tag)
    )
```

For more information you can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/multiple-voices#speech_transcribe_diarization_beta-python).

Comment: is there something similar to this but using a free service (no payment)? I want to recognize speakers using speech_recognition, but diarization fails most of the time